# variadic functions in macro and templates

Tags: c++, function, templates, macros, variadic

I try to create a macro that call a variadic function that uses a template.
I use the following code, but the linker cannot resolve a call to the macro...

This code is part of the Logger class:

```
template< typename ... Args >
void Logger::logTrace(Args const& ... args)
{
    std::ostringstream stream;
    using List = int[];
    (void)List{ 0, ((void)(stream << args), 0) ... };
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(log_, trace) << stream.str();
}
```

The logger class:

```
class Logger {

public:
    static Logger* getInstance(const char *logFile = "LogClient.log");

    template< typename ... Args >
    void logTrace(Args const& ... args);

private:
    Logger(std::string fileName);   
    virtual ~Logger();

    void initialize(std::string fileName);

    static Logger* logger_; // singleton instance
};
```

and the macro:

```
#define LOG_TRACE(...) Logger::getInstance()->logTrace(__VA_ARGS__);
```

A call to the macro:

```
LOG_TRACE("A log with a number: %d", 5);
```

Thanks for your help!

EDIT AND SOLVE:

The problem was not related to variadic function or even macro, but with linking.
Implement logTrace in the class definition resolve the problem.

code Working:

`The logger class:

```
class Logger {

public:
    static Logger* getInstance(const char *logFile = "LogClient.log");

    template< typename ... Args >
    void logTrace(Args const& ... args)
    {
        std::ostringstream stream;
        using List = int[];
        (void)List{ 0, ((void)(stream << args), 0) ... };
        BOOST_LOG_SEV(log_, trace) << stream.str();
    }

private:
    Logger(std::string fileName);   
    virtual ~Logger();

    void initialize(std::string fileName);

    static Logger* logger_; // singleton instance
};
```

and the macro:

```
#define LOG_TRACE(...) Logger::getInstance()->logTrace(__VA_ARGS__);
```

A call to the macro:

```
LOG_TRACE("A log with a number: %d", 5);
```

Comment: May you show the `Logger` class definition ?

Comment: I have updated the post

Comment: Why do you want to use a macro instead of a function?

Comment: What is the error message. Can you provide a minimal working example.

Comment: This is the error message: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl dhlogging::Logger::logWarn<char const [44]>(char const (&)[44])" (??$logWarn@$$BY0CM@$$CBD@Logger@dhlogging@@QEAEAY0CM@$$CBD@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl Player::Player(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,struct Position,class Ogre::Camera *)" (??0Player@@QEAA@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@0UPosition@@PEAVCamera@Ogre@@@Z)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have called your macro (and thus the logTrace template function) in a source file where `Logger::logTrace()` is declared but not defined/implemented (e.g.: in a source file where you included `Logger.h`). The full definition of the logTrace template function is required for your macro to work.

I suggest you define the logTrace member function into the Logger class:

```
class Logger {

public:
    static Logger* getInstance(const char *logFile = "LogClient.log");

    template< typename ... Args >
    void logTrace(Args const& ... args)
    { /* add implementation here */ }
    ...
```

Comment: Nice, it works fine! I edit the post with the solution, thank a lot